# Should the "respectively" be in the parenthesis?

Tags: grammar

Right now, I'm trying to translate a document into English, and while I was working, I noticed that in the original text, the adverb "respectively" was placed outside the brackets. By placing the said adverb outside of the parenthesis, am I correct that the sentence below would be a little confusing?

> "This concurs with the findings of the present study which found that difficulty sleeping has positive correlations with fatigue and anxiety (r = .287, r = .280 : p < .01) respectively."

I think in order to understand which statistic belongs to which variable (fatigue and anxiety in this case), the adverb "respectively" has be placed inside the brackets, am I correct?

I truly apologize for my lack of understanding (especially considering that someone translating something into English should know English!). I won't lie, I'm a complete newbie to English grammar and writing, and even online communication. I would appreciate any help provided to this very infantile user, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you could get rid of respectively completely to make it clearer

> This concurs with the findings of the present study which found that
>   difficulty sleeping has positive correlations with fatigue (r = .287 : p < .01) and anxiety (r = .280 : p < .01)

Comment: A better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct.  If you remove the parenthetical, you get:

> ...difficulty sleeping has positive correlations with fatigue and anxiety, respectively.

That doesn't make sense, because you are comparing one thing (difficulty sleeping) with two, so there's nothing for one of them to refer back to.

Also, the formulation of "This concurs with the findings of the present study which found..." is really awkward.  You only need "This concurs with the present study which found...".

All together, I'd instead write:

> "This concurs with the present study, which found that difficulty sleeping has positive correlations with fatigue and anxiety (r = .287, r = .280 : p < .01, respectively)."

Comment: Thinking of what the *respectively* applies to, maybe try: "This concurs with the present study, which found that difficulty sleeping has positive correlations with fatigue and anxiety (r = .287, r = .280, respectively : p < .01)."

Comment: @Nick2253 Thank you very much, sir! (or ma'am) I'll put the adverb right where it belongs! Now, I understand that the structure's awkward the way it was, and I'm sure to use your edit, but to be honest, I can't help translating literally from the original text. I mean, if the original work had "This concurs with the findings of the present study," I have a hard time deviating from that. Still, thank you for your great help, and I'm sure to come back for more. Do have a good day/night!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go even further and write it as follows:

> difficulty sleeping has positive correlations with fatigue and anxiety (*r* = .287, *r* = .280, respectively: *p* < .01).

...given that the things that you're treating as respective are the *r*-values, rather than the *p*-value.

I'd also italicize the variable labels *r* and *p*, which you might already be doing, though it wasn't reflected in your question.